# Responsive footer displayed over parts of content when shrinking browser

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer, responsive

I am fairly new to CSS and HTML.

And I understand that this question has been asked several times, yet I cannot seem to fix my current issue.

I have been working on little small projects like trying to recreate other websites with extra features.

My current task is recreating a front page search area, such as google.

### Implementation and Issue

I have been focusing in the responsiveness of websites when a browser resize occurs, so I have been using **Flexbox** as often as possible.

#### Implementation

A main div with a container id, with a min-height of 100% and a relative position.

Inside the container div are nav(#nav), center(#center) and footer(#footer) elements and their respective id's.

- **nav**: a flex display, baseline align-items and min-height of 9vh.
- **center**: a width of 100%, and a min-height of 10vh;
- **footer**: absolute position, bottom **0**, width of 100%

I have made some research into the Footer and how to keep it at the bottom  of a page while being responsive when shrinking the browser, but I seem to have come to a halt or possibly I haven't fully understood yet how to get the footer to stop at a certain element.

#### Issue

The issue is that I cannot get the footer to function correctly. I do not wish it to overlaps with the bottons and links in the main content. It stops at the search bar when resizing the browswer, but I would like it to stop when it meets the buttons.

As you will see from the block of code snippets in the JSbin link, I have an issue with the footer.

**Current HTML + CSS files and output**: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kojasimeco/edit?html,css,output)

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;  
}

#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;

}

a:visited{
    color: #609;
}

/* ----- Navigation Styling ----- */

#nav {
    display: flex;
    border: 10px solid  goldenrod;               /*Colourful Borders*/
    min-height:9vh;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    align-items: baseline;
    background:#ff0;
    padding:10px;
}

/*Nav Content*/

/* ----- Center Styling ----- */

#center {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    min-height:10vh;     
}

.ctr_img {
    height: 92px;
    width: 272x;
    padding-top: 20px;
    
}
.ctr_img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}

.img_mic {
    padding: 0 8px;
    float: right;
    display:inline-block;
    top: -30px;
    position: relative;
}

.srch_bx {
    border-style: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    max-width: 40%;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.srch_in {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    left: 0px;
    background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D) transparent;
    font: 16px arial,sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
}

.mic_set {
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 26px;
}

.btn_sbmt {
    padding: 20px 50%;
    min-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn_srch, .btn_lcky {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #757575;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 11px 4px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    height: 36px;
}
    
.lang_diff{
    max-height: 28px;
    font-size: 0.9vw;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}

/* Footer Styling */

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height: 5.2em; /* Height of the footer */
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10vh;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    line-height: 40px; /*Specifies the line height.*/
    min-width: 400px;


}

.ctry {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.54);
    border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    max-width: 150px;
}

.ctry_ftr {
    font-size: 1vw;
}

.opt_ftr {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    border:  1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

span.blft_ftr a, span.brght_ftr a, span.brght_stg a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

.brght_ftr{
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.adv_ftr {
    padding: 0 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Ground</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="http://www.favicon.cc/logo3d/53653.png" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>  <!--FLEX-->
        <div id="container"> <!-- Added New for Footer behaviour -->
            <nav id="nav" class="nav_cls">
                <!--Currently at work-->
                <p>Navigation Bar Content</p> 
            </nav>
            <center id="center">
                <a class="img_link" href="">
                    <img class="ctr_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png/250px-PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" alt="image">
                </a>
                <div class="in_forms">
                    <div class="srch_bx">
                        <form>
                            <input class="srch_in" type="text" name="search"/>
                        </form>
                        <div class="img_mic">
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/Ye8mB6VsUHw ">
                                <img class="mic_set" src="https://cdn.sesamestreet.org/sites/default/files/1496328210/Cookie_Big.png" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="btn_sbmt">
                        <input class="btn_srch" type="submit" value="Don't Hide me!" name="search"/>
                        <input class="btn_lcky" type="submit" value="Seriously, Don't!" name="luck"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="lang_diff">
                    Links:
                    <a class="lang" href="">Link1</a>
                    <a class="lang" href="">Link2</a>
                    <a class="lang" href="">Link3</a>
                    <a class="lang" href="">Link4</a>
                    <a class="lang" href="">Link5</a>
                </div>
            </center>
            <footer id="footer">
                <div class="ctry">
                    <span class="ctry_ftr">
                        First half of a footer 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="opt_ftr">
                    <span class="blft_ftr">
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 1</a>
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 2</a>
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 3</a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="brght_ftr">
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 4</a>
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 5</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Visited Websites

- [Footer is displayed over content. I need it always on the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865705/footer-is-displayed-over-content-i-need-it-always-on-the-bottom-of-the-page)
- [HTML, CSS - Sticky footer displays over content on screen resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319377/html-css-sticky-footer-displays-over-content-on-screen-resize)
- [Footer is displayed over content. I need it always on the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865705/footer-is-displayed-over-content-i-need-it-always-on-the-bottom-of-the-page)
- [How to keep footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)
- [Sticky Footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)
- [Footer overlaps main content when window shrunk](http://doctype.com/footer-overlaps-main-content-when-window-shrunk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:)

Congratulations, first of all, for following the rules of asking on SO.

Your problem comes from placing your footer out of document flow (`position:absolute`). It looks like you want it placed in document flow. So change `position:absolute` into `position:relative` (or `static`).

To keep it at the bottom of the screen at all times, adjust your `#container` to `display:flex;flex-direction:column;min-height:100vh` and make `#center` grow:

```
#footer {
  position:static; /* this is default value of position
                    * so you could just remove `position:absolute`
                    * from your code.
                    */
}
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#center {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

See it working:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

a:visited {
  color: #609;
}


/* ----- Navigation Styling ----- */

#nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 10px solid goldenrod;
  /*Colourful Borders*/
  min-height: 9vh;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: baseline;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 10px;
}


/*Nav Content*/


/* ----- Center Styling ----- */

#center {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 10vh;
}

.ctr_img {
  height: 92px;
  width: 272x;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.ctr_img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}

.img_mic {
  padding: 0 8px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -30px;
  position: relative;
}

.srch_bx {
  border-style: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  max-width: 40%;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.srch_in {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  left: 0px;
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D) transparent;
  font: 16px arial, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
}

.mic_set {
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 26px;
}

.btn_sbmt {
  padding: 20px 50%;
  min-height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn_srch,
.btn_lcky {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #757575;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 11px 4px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  height: 36px;
}

.lang_diff {
  max-height: 28px;
  font-size: 0.9vw;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Footer Styling */

#footer {
  /* position: absolute; 
     bottom: 0; */
  height: 5.2em;
  /* Height of the footer */
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  line-height: 40px;
  /*Specifies the line height.*/
  min-width: 400px;
}

.ctry {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.ctry_ftr {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.opt_ftr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

span.blft_ftr a,
span.brght_ftr a,
span.brght_stg a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 16px;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.brght_ftr {
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.adv_ftr {
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#footer {
  line-height: 2.42em;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#center {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- Added New for Footer behaviour -->
  <nav id="nav" class="nav_cls">
    <!--Currently at work-->
    <p>Navigation Bar Content</p>
  </nav>
  <center id="center">
    <a class="img_link" href="">
      <img class="ctr_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png/250px-PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" alt="image">
    </a>
    <div class="in_forms">
      <div class="srch_bx">
        <form>
          <input class="srch_in" type="text" name="search" />
        </form>
        <div class="img_mic">
          <a href="https://youtu.be/Ye8mB6VsUHw ">
            <img class="mic_set" src="https://cdn.sesamestreet.org/sites/default/files/1496328210/Cookie_Big.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="btn_sbmt">
        <input class="btn_srch" type="submit" value="Don't Hide me!" name="search" />
        <input class="btn_lcky" type="submit" value="Seriously, Don't!" name="luck" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lang_diff">
      Links:
      <a class="lang" href="">Link1</a>
      <a class="lang" href="">Link2</a>
      <a class="lang" href="">Link3</a>
      <a class="lang" href="">Link4</a>
      <a class="lang" href="">Link5</a>
    </div>
  </center>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="ctry">
      <span class="ctry_ftr">
                        First half of a footer 
                    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt_ftr">
      <span class="blft_ftr">
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 1</a>
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 2</a>
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 3</a>
                    </span>
      <span class="brght_ftr">
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 4</a>
                        <a class="adv_ftr" href="">Footer Link 5</a>
                    </span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Another minor issue which needed addressing was using `line-height` expressed in `px` for `#footer` while its height was expressed in `em`, causing the page to develop a vertical scrollbar. `line-height:2.42em` fixes it.

---

On a different note, it would be unfair of me to give you this answer without mentioning the major accessibility problem your example has from lowering font-size on narrow devices. Try opening the example page on any mobile and you'll understand what I mean. At all times, elements in your page should keep a font-size allowing users to read.

The main purpose of web pages is to present content. If you present the content in a form disabling user ability to receive the message, your page does not perform its function.

Comment: Thank you.

The accessibility problem, was made on purpose, mainly because I wanted to see how far I could push Flexbox before it collapsed.

I understand that it is not very practical when it comes down to devices such as smartphones and if a user decided to shrink the browser to the smallest point. :) 

I will keep that in mind and I will work in it to make it more user accessible.

Comment: I guess to make a good mobile version I would need to use [HTML Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)?
I don't think I am at that stage yet :)

Comment: You are :). The concept is quite simple: wrap some CSS in some `@media` condition. When condition is met, CSS inside applies. When not, it doesn't. See it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_responsive_media_query). And stop using W3Schools. they're not W3C (which is what you should be reading). If W3C is too technical, use MDN. But dump W3Schools, their content and examples are sub-par and sometimes plain wrong.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will use W3C and MDN from now on. 

I will start working on the mobile responsive side then. :)

Answer (score 1):

`#footer` is positioned absolutely, which means that the parent container doesn't know how big it is (i.e. it is outside of the "document flow"). `#container`'s height is set to `min-height: 100%`, so at a minimum, it needs to be the full height of the parent (in this case, the body), but if the child content is taller, it will stretch to accommodate that extra height.

Because `#footer` is not considered when`#container` is trying to figure out it's height, `#container` is just making sure it can fit it's other `position: static` or `position:relative` children.

So, when you scale down the height of your browser so it is very short, `#container` is too short - it doesn't leave space for the `#footer`.

There are a few ways to take care of this, though it is tricky from a responsive perspective if the height of the `#footer` is variable depending on the content and whether it wraps, etc.

If you know the height, you can add that amount of padding on the bottom of `#container` (if `box-sizing: border-box;` is turned on, it will not add onto the `height: 100%` - it will be included) and it will reserve the space for the `#footer`.

If you don't know the height, you could leverage `display: flex;` to fill the full height and have the footer self-align to the bottom, without needing to use `position: absolute;`.  Flexbox has a bit of a learning curve though, I would recommend you read through some tutorials. http://flexboxfroggy.com/ is a fun game that can also help to learn it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (it cleared some doubts I had) and the flexboxfroggy link (I will definitely go through it now)

Comment: Glad to help!  fwiw sticky footers are a pain, even to experienced developers - `height: 100%` works in simple layouts, but gets very hairy very fast (in order for a child's height to be a percentage, the parent must also have a defined height).